# Left join Query error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables events and enrolledevents  When a student registeres for an event the studentId and eventId is stored in stored into enrolledevents table
now i want to get all events which are not registered by student.

My Tables:
 Events Table[image]

EnrolledEvents
[image]

can any one give me the query I tried many queries But I didnt get the result

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    events
        LEFT JOIN
    enrolledevents ON events.event_id = enrolledevents.eevent_id
WHERE
    event_occurance = 'daily'
        AND status = '1'
        AND (enrolledevents.estudent_id NOT IN ('1')
        AND enrolledevents.eevent_id NOT IN ('3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the below `WHERE` conditions to `JOIN ON` clause

```
    AND (enrolledevents.estudent_id NOT IN ('1')
    AND enrolledevents.eevent_id NOT IN ('3'))
```

like

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    events
        LEFT JOIN
    enrolledevents ON events.event_id = enrolledevents.eevent_id
                   AND enrolledevents.estudent_id <> '1'
                   AND enrolledevents.eevent_id <> '3'
WHERE
    events.event_occurance = 'daily'
        AND events.status = '1';
```

Comment: sorry I didnt get you can you give me the full query

Comment: @sivasandeepgarapati, see edit in answer if that helps.